# Showing solution path in VS2008 window name

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to display the path of the solution in the Visual Studio window's name?

By default it displays (SolutionName) - Microsoft Visual Studio, I would like it to instead show something like (SolutionName) - (PathToSolution) - Microsoft Visual Studio.

The reason behind this is I can have multiple versions of a project checked out at a time (staging and trunk for example) and I'd like a quick way of checking without going through prompts etc.

Answer (score 1):

A good way of differential between trunk, staging, branches is to rename the solution file itself. For instance, when you work on a branch, rename the the solution file to *branch* and then you can always look at your title bare in Visual Studio to see what version you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. My ways to deal with this:

- order of icons in taskbar (Do you know [Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/)?)
- the path of any currently open file in editor (hover mouse over tab) usually shows which working copy the solution is from
- the solution's property windows (for me, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L` opens the solution window, `Pos1` marks the solution, `Alt`+`Enter` opens the property window)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WinSetTitle](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSetTitle.htm) command of AutoHotkey to set the title of any window.

So technically you could make a script to open a new instance of VS2008, load a specified solution, and set the window's title accordingly.

(however I don't know if VS2008 might reset the window title after some operation...)